# Accessing controls through threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I use WebBrowser Control in c# to check a couple search engine results but sometime for no reason it gets stuck. My first thought was to make each searching function as a thread and use thread.abort() from a timer but I just couldn't handle with the UI Controls (including the WebBrowser) no matter what I've tried. 
Anyone has a solution for me? an example would be great cause I already tried so many things and I keep getting all these exceptions.

Comment: What exactly is that you want to check out on those search engines? Why are you using a WebBrowser? Can't you use an HttpRequest?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use WebRequest in a Background worker & avoid the difficulties of dealing with the COM threading model.  You can use WebRequest.Timeout to handle anything you think is taking too long.

Try something like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
       bg.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;

       bg.RunWorkerAsync(new List<object> { "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/512MB.zip" });
       while (true) {}
   }

   private static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Starting operation.");
       BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

       List<object> args = (List<object>)e.Argument;

       var url = (string)args[0];
       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
       request.Timeout = 300;

       try
       {
           WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
           Console.WriteLine("Request successful.");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Request timed out.");
       }
   }
```

WebBrowser is a component you should use when you want to embed an instance of IE into your presentation layer.  Unless you need this, you can use something more lightwweight.

Answer (score 0):

Use the control's .Invoke() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

There are other methods you can use too: .BeginInvoke and .EndInvoke for asynchronous invokes.

```
if(control.InvokeRequired)
{
    control.Invoke(control.delegate);
}
```